# Difference in magnetic permeability of High tensile strength steel and Mild steel

Tags: electromagnetism, material-science

Mild steel has a relative magnetic permeability of 2000. High tensile steel is a type of mild steel with elements other than carbon. I need to know whether this would impact the relative permeability of the steel and by how much. I need a hex head bolt that has a relative permeability similar or greater than that of mild steel for an electromagnet core, however all mild steel bolts on the internet are of the high tensile steel kind.

Comment: Why not try it with just on cheap bold?

Comment: I could, but it would be hard for me to be able to distinguish a difference between even 500 and 2000. Whereas the 2000 would be necessary for the final project. I'd rather know the precise factors now